# No lauch activity found

Tags: android, manifest, launch

i have a problem with my Android Application. The Error occures when i want to run my Application on the emulator or a real device:

```
[2012-03-27 12:01:30 - CallApp] Android Launch!
[2012-03-27 12:01:30 - CallApp] adb is running normally.
[2012-03-27 12:01:30 - CallApp] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-03-27 12:01:30 - CallApp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2012-03-27 12:01:30 - CallApp] Performing sync
[2012-03-27 12:01:30 - CallApp] Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets. Please select a target device.
[2012-03-27 12:01:32 - CallApp] Uploading CallApp.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2012-03-27 12:01:33 - CallApp] Installing CallApp.apk...
[2012-03-27 12:01:36 - CallApp] Success!
[2012-03-27 12:01:36 - CallApp] \CallApp\bin\CallApp.apk installed on device
[2012-03-27 12:01:36 - CallApp] Done!
```

I already checked my Manifest-File, but there are the necessary Launcher and MAIN statements:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.CallApp.CallApp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.BootBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".receiver.SmsBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="99999999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="de.CallApp.CallApp.CallAppActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your whole manifest file.

Comment: do you add SDCARD to your emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the *intent filters* for your activity **de.CallApp.CallApp.CallAppActivity** as below:

```
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW" />
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
  </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should split the actions to multiple intent-filters.
Like:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BATTERY_LOW" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Else it wont be recognized